# Mongoose .populate()

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am a beginner.

I have two mongoose schema, orders and customers.

orders schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    customer: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Customer"}    
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Order", orderSchema);
```

customers schema

```
const mongoose        = require("mongoose"),
passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

const customerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String
    username: String,
    password: String
});

customerSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model("Customer", customerSchema);
```

This is my code when I insert new order

```
const Orders = require("../models/orders");

Orders.create({customer: req.user});
```

I want to console.log() all the orders and customers by using .populate()

Here is my code

```
Orders.find({}).populate("customers").exec((err, order) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(order);
    }
});
```

I want to get the customer's id, name, and email but the problem is I only get the customer's id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Orders.find({}).populate("customer").exec((err, order) => {
if(err) {
    console.log(err);
} else {
    console.log(order);
}
})

or you can try

    Orders.find({}).populate({path:"customer"}).exec((err, order) => {
if(err) {
    console.log(err);
} else {
    console.log(order);
}
```

})