# i want to populate mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I want to get Products details when user order their item so I saved in Order schema where I passed ref of my product schema in productId
here is my  Schema :

```js
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const OrderSchema=new Schema({
productId:[{_id:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'products'},quantity:{type:Number}}],
 status:{type:Number,required:true},
    deliverDate:{type:String},
    totalAmount:{type:Number,default:0},
    userId:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'userDetail'},
    Address:{type:Object,required:true},
    totalquantity:{type:Number,default:0},
    name:{type:String},
    method:{type:String,required:true},
    txnId:{type:String},
    pushToken:{type:String},
    coordinates: {
        type: [Number, Number],
        index: '2d'
    },
},{timestamps: true})

module.exports=mongoose.model('orders',OrderSchema)
```

I want to fetch an Order which populates productId with all products details:

```js
Order.findById(id)
      .then(order=>{
        res.json({
            orders:order
        })
    }).catch(err=>{console.log(err);next("Network error")})
```

How can I populate productId?

Comment: Check If this post solves your problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62014003/mongoose-populate?r=SearchResults

Comment: Thank you so much it solve my problem